# X-editable doesn't check up checked checklist values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, x-editable

Good day guys. In a Laravel application I'm working on, I'm using the X-editable library for inline editing options. I'have a many to many relationship table (pivot table) that I need to update. To do so I'm trying to utilize X-editable **checklist** option as seen in the docs: [checklist](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#checklist)

The problem I'm facing is whenever I click on one of the values to edit the checklist dialog pops out but the value I clicked on isn't checked. Here is a picture that better illustrate this:

[image: checklist image]

From the picture you see that the values to be checked are **Senior High**, **Junior High** and **Elementary**, but they are not check and I can't figure out why.

This is how my view looks:

```
<td>
    <!-- If a subject belongs to a division or divisions list all the divisions
    that belongs to the subject -->
    @if(count($subject->divisions))
        @foreach($subject->divisions as $division)

            <a href="#" data-type="checklist" data-value="{{$division->id}}" data-title="Select divisions" data-name="division" class="division" data-pk="{{$division->id}}" role="button">
                <span class="badge label-primary">{{$division->name}}</span>
            </a> 

        @endforeach
    @endif
</td>
```

controller:

```
 public function index(Request $request)
{
    //

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $divisions = Division::all();

        return $divisions->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
    }
    //return view('division.show', compact('divisions'));
}
```

script:

```
$('#subjects').editable({
    mode:'popup',
    container:'body',
    selector:'a.division',
    type:'checklist',
    source: function () {
        // body...
        var result;


        $.ajax({
            url: '/divisions',
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            global  : false,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function (data) {
                // body...

                console.log(data);

                result = data;

            }
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log("success");
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            console.log("error");
            console.log(data);
        });

        return result;
        console.log(result);

    }
});
```

result from source:

[image]

Comment: let me know if this answered your question, albeit several months after you asked it.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

The following code is the example used at the [Xeditable site](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html).

```
<a href="#" id="options" data-type="checklist" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Select options"></a>


<script>
$(function(){
    $('#options').editable({
        value: [2, 3],    
        source: [
              {value: 1, text: 'option1'},
              {value: 2, text: 'option2'},
              {value: 3, text: 'option3'}
           ]
    });
});
</script>
```

The "value: [2, 3]," is the relevant portion.

Right now, your data-value statement in the link looks to produce the text of the value without the syntax of a javascript array.